# SQL stored Procedures : How to avoid repeating statements in case when exists... Then

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is meant for MS Sql Server 2008

I have a Stored procedure like

```
Select
case when exists (select top 1 ID from table.....) 
then (select top 1 ID from table.....) 
As COLUMN1
.....
```

the above keeps repeating for other columns

Question:
since the sql in both WHEN and THEN are the same, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why dont you try using a dynamic query?

Comment: @TechGirl could you please elaborate why a dynamic query can be used here? I am also looking at performance when using the dynamic query

Comment: What is the whole query? What is returned if it does not exist? Also are the "other columns" looking up different columns in the same row?

Comment: @martin, the whole query is a typical Stored procedure which returns multiple columns. there are multiple columns selected from different tables and the one of the columns is based on the case statement I mentioned in the question. Does that help or is there anything specific you are expecting? Thanks

Comment: The SQL you posted returns 1 value if the record exists or NULL if it doesn't. (since there is no ELSE) so you should be able to simplify to `Select
 (select top 1 ID from table.....)  As COLUMN1`

Answer (score 1):

You give little information about the rest of the query.  I think cross apply will solve the problem:

```
select coalesce(t1.ıd, . . .)
from <whatever> cross apply
     (select id from table where . . . ) t1
     . . .
```

There may be simpler solutions, but this will work for general cases, including correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:

```
declare @a int

SElect top 1 @a = ID  from Table Where ....

select case when @a IS not null then @a ELSE ...
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Has per your question I think it would be easy to use a prepared statement  like

```
declare @statement nvarchar(max)
set @statement='case when exists (select top 1 ID from table.....) then (select top 1 ID from table.....)'
```

by doing this, you just need to use this variable where you needed that's what I think